# input file type error validation not working using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Currently working on input file error validation When i searched about the validation i have found jquery validation so i have started using it and again when i searched about how to validate the input file i have got some useful information from **SO** Based on that I have created error validation page for input file. With my current code I can able to upload pdf & Jpeg file and view the file but the validation was not happening if user click next button without uploading any file it should say you have 2 files missed if the user upload one file and he click next button it should say you have 1 file miss. I have tried giving required in the html input type field and tried giving required in jquery validation nothing was working.

Here is my jquery code

```
   $(".attachForm").validate({
        ignore: false,
         onkeyup: false,
            showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
            var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();

            if (errors) {
                var message = errors === 0 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' : 'You have missed ' + errors + ' fields. Please fill before submitted.';
                $("#error_message").html(message);
                $(".error_msge").show();
            } else {
                $(".error_msge").hide();
            }
            this.defaultShowErrors();
        },
        errorPlacement: function () {
            return false;
        },
        highlight: function (element) {

            if($('input').attr('type') == 'checkbox') {

            } else {
               $(element).addClass('errRed');
                $(".file_ipt").addClass('errRed');
            }
            $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-red').removeClass('text-error-black');            
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {

            if($('input').attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
            } else {
                $(element).removeClass('errRed');
                $(".file_ipt").addClass('errRed');
            }
            $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-black').removeClass('text-error-red');

        },rules: {
        apt_code:"required",
        apt_cer:"required",
        checkfile:"required"
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
        return false; // for demo
    }
    });
```

I tried changing the name in all field but no use

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/9Lrw5vz5/) for the detailed code

Kindly please suggest me. kindly guide as i am not getting any stuff :(

Thanks for looking the question.

Comment: The reason why the code isn't working is because this.numberOfInvalids(); doesn't yield any errors. Check your implementation.

Comment: @DinoMyte thanks for the reply i am giving required in all the field and i am confused how to solve this kindly please help me :(

Comment: You might wanna add class="required" to your code. Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/UURz2/

Comment: @DinoMyte in the text field or in the jquery code buddy class="required"

Comment: @DinoMyte i tired with the given example still not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the unique `name` attribute to each `<input type="file" class="checkfile">`

```
<input type="file" class="checkfile" name="file_alpha">
<input type="file" class="checkfile" name="file_beta">
```

and then in `rules` you have to define both fields and make sure they are `required`

```
rules: {
   file_alpha: {
        checkfile: "required",
        required: true,
   },
   file_beta: {
        checkfile: "required",
        required: true,
   }
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lrw5vz5/1/)

**Correct Solution**

Above solution will work because assigning the unique `name` and `required` rules set will trigger the validation but will not return the desired result because OP trying to validate the input with same `name` attribute and triggering the error counter according to number of invalid input fields.

Reason the validation not working in original code because no required rules

```
rules: {
    checkfile:"required"
},
```

defined anywhere.

so work around is set `required` rules and add to inputs with same `name` attribute OR `type` using jQuery `each()` function

```
$("input[type=file]").each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
    });
});
```

and validation will work, errors will triggered with counter and on validating the input field, error counter decrease as like OP's desired output.

[Fiddle Proper Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9Lrw5vz5/3/)

Comment: thank you so much for the effort but the counting was not reducing kindly please help me when i upload for one field

Comment: kindly please help me

Comment: looking into that, give me some time

Comment: Is that possible to bind after file upload

Comment: there are couple of things in your code, why there is `if($('input').attr('type') == 'checkbox') ` and where the rule is defined `checkfile:"required"` i don't see any `checkfile` function in code

Comment: You can remove the code this was just the part of my jquery code I have big page which contain lot  of fields